# Unity3d - switch between multiple monitors on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, crash, unity-game-engine, multiple-monitors

I want to be able to switch the monitor on which the Unity3D view is shown in Android.
For example when a HDMI monitor is plugged into a tablet the View should go from the tablet screen to the external screen.

The [PresentationWithMediaRouterActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html) does exactly what I want for an OpenGL cube View.

When I try to use the Unity View in stead of the Cube View the app crashes.

First I [modified the example](http://pastebin.com/euxhtnse) in which one View is used all the time in stead of creating the View each time.
Secondly I [replaced the GLSurfaceView by UnityPlayer](http://pastebin.com/h8xA9Pgv). It works correctly the first time, but when I switch from monitor (by plugging HDMI cable in or removing it) it crashes:

```
E/Unity(2201): Id not found in map
E/Unity(2201): UnityEngine.TerrainRenderer:RenderStep3(Camera, Int32, Boolean, Material)
E/Unity(2201): UnityEngine.Terrain:CullAllTerrains(Int32)
E/Unity(2201): [Runtime/Profiler/MemoryProfiler.cpp line 546] 
E/Unity(2201): (Filename: Runtime/Profiler/MemoryProfiler.cpp Line: 546)
E/Unity(2201): Id not found in map
E/Unity(2201): UnityEngine.TerrainRenderer:RenderStep3(Camera, Int32, Boolean, Material)
E/Unity(2201): UnityEngine.Terrain:CullAllTerrains(Int32)
E/Unity(2201): [Runtime/Profiler/MemoryProfiler.cpp line 546] 
E/Unity(2201): (Filename: Runtime/Profiler/MemoryProfiler.cpp Line: 546)
A/libc(2201): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 2267 (Thread-162)`
```